# How do I start Emacs with the debug init option?

Tags: emacs, debug

The warning that I get, as soon as I open Emacs is this:

> Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading
>   `/Users/Kaileeena/.emacs':
>
> End of file during parsing: /Users/Kaileeena/.emacs
>
> To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
>   cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with the
>   `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.

But how do I do that?

I've never used this software before, and I can't figure out where to even type.

Comment: That ususally means -- You missed a bracket in `.emacs` -- or some package that You `require` missed that. Try to recall what You've been fidling with recently.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're running Mac OS, right?  Assuming you installed Emacs into the Applications folder, open a Terminal window (it's in the Utilities subfolder inside Applications) and type:

```
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs --debug-init
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm getting the same result as when I tried that through Emacs. All I see is a blank window. I was wondering if there should be some sort of log that would tell me exactly why I'm getting the warning in the first place?

Comment: Hm, `--debug-init` should show you where the problem is... You could try adding `-nw` ("no window") to that command line.  It will make Emacs run inside the terminal window, which might make it less confused.

Comment: can this applied for the emacsclient?

Comment: can this applied for the `emacsclient`?

Comment: @alper I think you could do it with the `-a` option, e.g. `emacsclient -a "emacs --debug-init"`, so that it would start emacs with the debug init option in case it couldn't find a running emacs instance.

Comment: Seems like it did not work, `emacs --daemon` and ` emacs --debug-init -nw ~/doo` runs their own daemon

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the suggestions to use `emacs --debug-init`, do this: Bisect your init file (`~/.emacs`) recursively until you find the problematic code.  (E.g., use `M-x comment-region` to comment out half the code, then 1/4, then 1/8, then 1/16,...  (With prefix arg `C-u` the same command uncomments the region.)

This is a binary search, so it is very quick to do.

But as @Adobe suggested, it is likely that you are missing one or more closing parens.  Another approach is to use `C-M-f` repeatedly (just hold down that chord), until you get the error. That will be where you are missing a paren.  (Start at the top level of the file and the leftmost paren of your first sexp.)

Comment: Drew has the right idea, but there's a better way to go about it: use "bug-hunter", which is an emacs package that automatically does the bisection search for you.

Answer (score 1):

When you start emacs from a terminal simply add it after the command so that your complete command looks like `emacs --debug-init`.

Answer (score 1):

Just write `emacs --debug-init` in your terminal, you can do `M-x info RET` to see the other options and learn what is for what.